# C++ ,visual studio 2019 , float type，i have float number 20000115 to parse， but it will change to 20000116. how to fix this bug?

Tags: c++

```
    float a = 20000115;
    cout << a;
```

in debug , variable window is   20000116. why?  how to fix this bug?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofh6F.png)
like this image

Comment: That number requires 25 bits to represent exactly. A float has 23 bits available to represent an exact value. It's not a bug, it is simply the way floating point values work. Not all numbers can be exactly represented. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for the long explanation.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Although you are probably correct in this case (and using `double` would "solve" this specific problem), the size of a `float` is C++ is at the discretion of the particular compiler.

Answer (score 3):

This is called precision loss. It's not a bug. Use `double` instead of `float`, it will solve the issue.